# Singleton instance, how to write write self

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I am looking for a way to extend our default logging class without making changes to the whole application or library. We have a number of places where we write logs. E.g:

```
App_Log::getInstance()->write(
    $name,
    $type,
    "LOGOUT",
    $url
);
```

Auth_Log

```
<?php
class App_Auth_Log {

    /**
     * Singleton instance
     *
     * Marked only as protected to allow extension of the class. To extend,
     * simply override {@link getInstance()}.
     *
     * @var App_Auth_Log
     */
    protected static $_instance = null;


    /**
     * Auth logging enabled flag.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_enabled = false;


    /**
     * If flag is true then cleanup will not remove login records.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_keepLoginRecords = false;


    /**
     * Class constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        if(App_Front::getInstance()->hasParam("withAuthLog"))
            $this->_enabled = true;

        if(App_Front::getInstance()->hasParam("withKeepLoginRecords"))
            $this->_keepLoginRecords = true;

        $this->cleanup();
    }


    /**
     * Singleton instance
     *
     * @return App_Auth_Log
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (is_null(self::$_instance))
            self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    }


    /**
     * Write new auth log record with given details. if succesful then method
     * returns true otherwise returns false.
     *
     * @param string $class
     * @param string $ident
     * @param string $action
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $ipaddr
     * @return boolean
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function write($class,$ident,$action,$url,$ipaddr=null) {

        if($this->isEnabled())  {
            $db = App_Db_Connections::getInstance()->getConnection();
            try {

                // if address not specificed get remote addr
                $ipaddr = ($ipaddr == null) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : $ipaddr;

                // manual insert so we can take advantage of insert delayed
                $stmnt = "INSERT INTO accesslogs
                    VALUES('',NOW(),'$class','$ident','$action','$url','$ipaddr')";

                // execute insert
                $db->query($stmnt);

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Cleanup old accesslog records. Cached to run once a day.
     *
     * @return boolean - returns true if run false if not.
     */
    public function cleanup() {

        $cache  = App_Cache::getInstance()->newObject(86400);

        if($this->isEnabled()) {

            if (!$res = $cache->load(App_Cache::getCacheName(__CLASS__. "cleanup"))) {
                // add cache
                $db = App_Db_Connections::getInstance()->getConnection();
                try {
                    $where = $db->quoteInto("DATEDIFF(NOW(),accesslog_datetime) > ?", 6);
                    $and = ($this->_keepLoginRecords) ? " AND accesslog_action != 'LOGIN'" : "";
                    $db->query("DELETE LOW_PRIORITY FROM accesslogs WHERE $where $and");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw $e;
                }


                $cache->save($res,App_Cache::getCacheName(__CLASS__. "cleanup"));
            } // end cache
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Returns boolean check if auth log enabled.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isEnabled() {
        return ($this->_enabled) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Enabled disable the auth log process.
     *
     * @param boolean $boolean
     * @return App_Auth_Log
     */
    public function setEnabled($boolean) {
        $this->_enabled = ($boolean) ? true : false;
        return $this;
    }
}
?>
```

This is the default behaviour of the core code. But for this specific project I need to be able to extend/overwrite the `write` method, e.g with extra parameters.

**Q:** How can I make changes to this App_Auth_Log class so that its backwards compatible with previous projects that call `App_Log::getInstance()->write`?

How I think it should work(but dont know how to do it).
If `App_Front::getInstance()->hasParam("withAuthLog")` passes a custom class name e.g: `My_Custom_Auth_Log` which overwrites the original write method. Just not sure how to modify the singleton part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no choice. You *have* to modify your `App_Log` code, because everything statically makes calls to it. For minimal changes, you could `extend` the `App_Log` class and make `App_Log::getInstance` return an instance of that child class; but that's pretty messy, since a parent should never know about its children.

Maybe you can prevent the default implementation of `App_Log` to be loaded and load a different implementation of it from a different file. That's pretty messy too though.

This is exactly (one of) the reason(s) why singletons and static calls are very frowned upon. See [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/).